# Prevent Race Condition in .NET 6 - MVC Application with lock()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, locking, race-condition, .net-6.0

In order to mitigate race condition in my .NET 6 (Core) application, I'm trying to lock a functionality, thus each user will be able to access it only once at a time (multiple users can access it simultaneously, however each of them only once).

As you can see in the simplified code, this functionality handles a money transfer and it takes time to make the transfer.

The issue is that if I send multiple requests at a time (from the same user) the transfer will occur multiple times even if the user doesn't have sufficient amount of money (I thought that my lock should prevent this behavior, but it doesn't).

Example Code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Withdraw()
{
    string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    lock (String.Intern(userId))
    {
         if(user.HasMoney()){
             TransferMoney(); // this one takes time
             SendEmail();
         }
    }
```

Do you have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `lock` will not help if you have several servers processing requests.

Comment: It also won't work if there are several app instances on the same server, or several app domains within the same app instance. The proper solution is to use an external system, like a database.

Comment: I have only one server, and one running instance, however, it's still not working, can't figure out why. I'm running a single IIS application in which my app is running, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Web applications are stateless. When a client's request is received, an instance of the relevant Controller is created for that request. When the response is sent, that instance of the Controller ceases to exist.

In order to prevent a new transaction while the old transaction is in progress, you need to save that data somewhere more permanent, like a database.

```
var lastTransaction = await dbContext.Transactions.Where(t => t.UserId == userId).OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (lastTransaction.IsComplete)
{
  await Transfer();
  await SendEmail();
}
else
{
  // tell user it's not ready yet.
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't have any table for those operations, it just updates the TotalAvailable of the user, is there any other workaround you can think of?
Thanks!

Comment: If it's just one property, wait for the update to complete before returning the response to the user. Otherwise, you'll need to add in more detail in order to tell if there is a transaction in progress.

Comment: The problem is that if a malicious user will send two identical requests this property will be updated twice as well as two emails will be sent. It seems like the core issue won't be solved

Comment: You can prevent accidental double-submits on the client side with JavaScript, but detecting double-submits on the server side is going to need you to keep track of transactions that are in progress.

Comment: You could also try IMemoryCache, bring it in with Dependency Injection. It's in System.Runtime.Caching.

Basically, when the request starts, write to cache something that has the user ID and transaction in progress. When the request is done, clear that cache key/value out. Any duplicate requests will see the transaction is in progress and can tell the user to cool it.